# javascript overriding a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, overriding

This might be rediculous, asking about such a huge bit of code...but basically I have a whole section that loops through 4 divs of content. that works fine. Then i have a section on if you hover over a div, that section will stay active, or if you click the div it will stay constantly active. that bit works on its own aswell. but when i combine them, i have the problem that the loop will always work even if you are hovering, because the loop never stops.

Now, is there a way to make the hover and click bit also pause the loop section. essentailly i am trying to code my own smaller version of all those sliders you see on the internetz

thanks.

```
$(window).load(function(){
var clicked = 0;
var i = 1;                    
var j = (i - 1);

function myLoop () {       
setTimeout(function () {
   if (clicked == 0) {
$("#nHstuff4").hide();$("#nHpicture4").hide();
$("#nH4").removeClass("active"); 

$("#nHstuff" + j).hide();$("#nHpicture" + j).hide();     
$("#nH" + j).removeClass("active");

$("#nHstuff" + i).show();$("#nHpicture" + i).show();
$("#nH" + i).addClass("active");

        i++;
        j++;

  if (i < 5) {        
     myLoop();        
  }   
  else if (i == 5) {
      i = 1;
      j = 0;
      myLoop();
  } 
   }else{} } ,3000);
}

myLoop();                     

$("#nH1").click(function() {
    if (clicked == 0) {
        clicked = 1;
        $("#nH1").addClass("active");
    }else if (clicked == 1) {
        $(".nHstuff").hide();
        $(".nH").removeClass("active");
        clicked = 0;
    }
});
    $("#nH2").click(function() {
    if (clicked == 0) {
        clicked = 1;
        $("#nH2").addClass("active");
    }else if (clicked == 1) {
        $(".nHstuff").hide();
        $(".nH").removeClass("active");
        clicked = 0;
    }
});
    $("#nH3").click(function() {
    if (clicked == 0) {
        clicked = 1;
        $("#nH3").addClass("active");
    }else if (clicked == 1) {
        $(".nHstuff").hide();
        $(".nH").removeClass("active");
        clicked = 0;
    }
});
    $("#nH4").click(function() {
    if (clicked == 0) {
        clicked = 1;
        $("#nH4").addClass("active");
    }else if (clicked == 1) {
        $(".nHstuff").hide();
        $(".nH").removeClass("active");
        clicked = 0;
    }
});

$("#nH1").hover(function() {if (clicked == 0) {
    $("#nH1stuff").show();$("#nH1picture").show();
}else{}},function(){
    if (clicked == 0) {
    $("#nH1stuff").hide();$("#nH1picture").hide();
    }
    else {}
});

$("#nH2").hover(function() {if (clicked == 0) {
    $("#nH2stuff").show();$("#nH2picture").show();
}else{}},function(){
    if (clicked == 0) {
    $("#nH2stuff").hide();$("#nH2picture").hide();
    }
    else {}
});

$("#nH3").hover(function() {if (clicked == 0) {
    $("#nH3stuff").show();$("#nH3picture").show();
}else{}},function(){
    if (clicked == 0) {
    $("#nH3stuff").hide();$("#nH3picture").hide();
    }
    else {}
}); 

$("#nH4").hover(function() {if (clicked == 0) {
    $("#nH4stuff").show();$("#nH4picture").show();
}else{}},function(){
    if (clicked == 0) {
    $("#nH4stuff").hide();$("#nH4picture").hide();
    }
    else {}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
$(window).load(function(){
var clicked = 0;
var i = 1;                    
var j = (i - 1);
var hovering = false;

function myLoop () {       
setTimeout(function () {
    if (hovering) return;
   if (clicked == 0) {
$("#nHstuff4").hide();$("#nHpicture4").hide();
$("#nH4").removeClass("active"); 

$("#nHstuff" + j).hide();$("#nHpicture" + j).hide();     
$("#nH" + j).removeClass("active");

$("#nHstuff" + i).show();$("#nHpicture" + i).show();
$("#nH" + i).addClass("active");

        i++;
        j++;

  if (i < 5) {        
     myLoop();        
  }   
  else if (i == 5) {
      i = 1;
      j = 0;
      myLoop();
  } 
   }else{} } ,3000);
}

myLoop();                     

$("#nH1").click(function() {
    if (clicked == 0) {
        clicked = 1;
        $("#nH1").addClass("active");
    }else if (clicked == 1) {
        $(".nHstuff").hide();
        $(".nH").removeClass("active");
        clicked = 0;
    }
});
    $("#nH2").click(function() {
    if (clicked == 0) {
        clicked = 1;
        $("#nH2").addClass("active");
    }else if (clicked == 1) {
        $(".nHstuff").hide();
        $(".nH").removeClass("active");
        clicked = 0;
    }
});
    $("#nH3").click(function() {
    if (clicked == 0) {
        clicked = 1;
        $("#nH3").addClass("active");
    }else if (clicked == 1) {
        $(".nHstuff").hide();
        $(".nH").removeClass("active");
        clicked = 0;
    }
});
    $("#nH4").click(function() {
    if (clicked == 0) {
        clicked = 1;
        $("#nH4").addClass("active");
    }else if (clicked == 1) {
        $(".nHstuff").hide();
        $(".nH").removeClass("active");
        clicked = 0;
    }
});

$("#nH1").hover(function() {if (clicked == 0) {
    hovering = true;
    $("#nH1stuff").show();$("#nH1picture").show();
}else{}},function(){
    hovering = false;
    if (clicked == 0) {
    $("#nH1stuff").hide();$("#nH1picture").hide();
    }
    else {}
});

$("#nH2").hover(function() {if (clicked == 0) {
    hovering = true;
    $("#nH2stuff").show();$("#nH2picture").show();
}else{}},function(){
    hovering = false;
    if (clicked == 0) {
    $("#nH2stuff").hide();$("#nH2picture").hide();
    }
    else {}
});

$("#nH3").hover(function() {if (clicked == 0) {
    hovering = true;
    $("#nH3stuff").show();$("#nH3picture").show();
}else{}},function(){
    hovering = false;
    if (clicked == 0) {
    $("#nH3stuff").hide();$("#nH3picture").hide();
    }
    else {}
}); 

$("#nH4").hover(function() {if (clicked == 0) {
    hovering = true;
    $("#nH4stuff").show();$("#nH4picture").show();
}else{}},function(){
    hovering = false;
    if (clicked == 0) {
    $("#nH4stuff").hide();$("#nH4picture").hide();
    }
    else {}
});
});
```

I've simply added the variable `hovering` and I set it to true when hovering and false when not.  Then I added a conditional return in the timeout. (It's similar to what you did with `clicked`, but using a boolean value rather than an integer).

There's a better way to do the timeout.  You could use `setInterval` so you don't have to keep calling it, and you could then `clearInterval` when hovering and do another `setInterval` when you stop hovering.  What you have will work though.  Just do some googling about `setInterval` as it's more appropriate for something like this.

Incidentally, kudos for making your own version and learning how to do it, rather than just using a plugin :)  Plugins are great and usually very handy, but you can't beat knowing how to do it yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Save the value of the timerID in a variable.

```
var loopTimer = 0;
function myLoop() {
   loopTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      //All your loop code
   }, 30000);
}
```

Clear the timeout on hover and restart it when you mouse out:

```
$("#nH1").hover(function() {if (clicked == 0) {
   hovering = true;
    $("#nH1stuff").show();$("#nH1picture").show();
   clearTimeout(loopTimer);
    }
  },function() {
    hovering = false;
    if (clicked == 0) {
    $("#nH1stuff").hide();$("#nH1picture").hide();
    myLoop(); //restart your loop
    }
 });
```

Look into using setInterval for regularly scheduled events on a known interval.  It'll make the code a little easier to understand.